# Is it possible to recover a gamertag/account from a (fat) Xbox 360 with no hard drive?

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-360

When the slim 360's came out, I traded in my white 20gb model without the hard drive. I assumed that all profile/gamertag information was on the hard drive.

Fast forward to today and I see that someone logged into my account, spent my points, played a game, changed the avatar, etc.

I was not the victim of any social engineering, etc. The only thing I can think of is that my old console allowed the purchaser to log into my XBL account, even though I still have my original hard drive.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is very strange.  The only way the new owner could have access to your profile is if it were saved on internal memory.  And even then only if you haven't logged into your account on your new Xbox.  As tzenes said, I would recommend contacting Microsoft.

Comment: It could also be possible if the profile were saved on a MU that was then traded in with the 360 and sold as a package. The new owner could then load the profile off the MU, but again, only if the account hadn't yet been used on the new 360 (or any other 360).

Answer (score 5):

So, a gamer tag can only be associated with 1 memory device at a time.

If you transfer to another hard drive, or memory unit, or recover it to a new Xbox, the old gamer tag will be unable to log into Xbox live.

There is a single exception to this rule.  If you duplicate the profile (which would require custom modifications and void your warranty), then the first profile to log in will become the main one, and the other will not work.

Regardless, you should not be able to log in, if someone else is able to.  If you're finding that is the case, I would recommend you contact Xbox directly about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a link for Move, Delete and Recovery of gamer tags.. They are tied to a console (For those who got a new XBox, if you wondered why you could play your XBL Arcade games offline on your original XBox but not the new one, its cause you need to make the new one your official one :))

Anywho, hope this helps :)

http://support.xbox.com/en-us/pages/xbox-live/how-to/xbox-live-account-management/gamer-profile.aspx

Comment: My comment was referring entirely to OFFline play, not logged in play. I have yet to come across a game from XBL that did not allow me to play it at any location as long as I was logged in. I have seen some that require me to be player 1, but nothing beyond that.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking more about offline play on the console purchasing the license. You're right that offline play on a different console won't work. WRT licenses failing on the licensed console (my original comment, I deleted it for being mostly off-topic) ... it isn't common, thankfully - I've seen it on a few of the older XBLA games, but not on anything recent (yet). It can be especially nasty, though, if you lose connectivity during a session and suddenly go from being "licensed" to "unlicensed" ...

Answer (score 2):

With the new upgrade of the user interface a couple of months ago, it now allows the same gamertag to be on multiple consoles and NOT have to redownload or update it. I have two xboxs, one for me and another for my housemates and I notice when my housemates use my account on a different system. When I log on to a different xbox than the previous one I logged into, I get a pop up now that says I was on a different console previously. Although you kept your hard drive, do you still have another system or a friends system you left your gamertag on?

Anyways to prevent this from happening again, you can create either a button combination password or a number password to lock your account to keep off of it.